# How to stretch UniForm image to buttons content in WINRT

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, windows-runtime

I am using [CameraCaptureUI API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn376408.aspx) to capture and save pictures which I load in a button as the following XAML.

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Width="150" Height="150">
                <Button.Content>
                    <Image x:Name="coffejpg" Stretch="Uniform" />
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

The code behind code:

```
namespace App1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            coffejpg.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/coffe.jpg"));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the result from the loading of the coffee file which I capture with the webcam.

[image]

How can I stretch the picture to the buttons border. I've tried with `VerticalAlignment` and `HorizontalAlignment` properties of the image. Also tried with Height and Width but they deform the picture.

The **Stretch** property must be Uniform **explicitly**

This is just a test scenario.

Comment: Have you tried `Stretch="Fill"`?

Comment: The Stretch must be UniForm in any matter and even if so it still does not take the whole content of the button.

Comment: @MartinZPetrov Then you can try `UniformToFill`.

Comment: Its must be UniForm I`ll have to acomplish it with that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on using `Stretch=Uniform` then you need to understand what it does. It preserves the aspect ratio of the image.  Therefore if the original picture is 800x600 the image will keep a 4x3 ratio.  You are attempting to put an image in a 1x1 ratio button but the image itself is not a 1x1 ratio.  So there will be blank space around the button.

If you don't want to use UniformToFill then the other solution is to change the size of the button.

Try setting only one dimension on the button.

```
 <Button Width="150" Height="Auto">
```

or

```
 <Button Width="Auto" Height="150">
```